# Mounting Google Compute persistent disk at boot

Tags: centos6, google-compute-engine, fstab

I have a new google compute engine instance running CentOS6 with two persistent storage volumes attached.  I have followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

My attached volumes are:

```
/dev/sdb or /dev/disk/by-id/google-admin-backup
/dev/sdc or /dev/disk/by-id/google-admin-media
```

/etc/fstab looks like:

```
UUID=6e64a346-b01d-45d6-8bb0-549535b4b3cc /                       ext4    defaults,barrier=1 1 1
/dev/sdb        /backups        ext4    defaults    0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/google-admin-media /www/icapture/capture    ext4    discard,defaults    1   1
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

*note: I realize that I am pointing at the disks differently, I have tried both by doing the /dev/sdc and the /by-id/ way*

My problem is that when I reboot the machine /www/icapture/capture doesn't mount.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        59G  5.3G   51G  10% /
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb        493G   70M  467G   1% /backups
```

However, I can simply do

```
sudo mount /www/icapture/capture
```

And it mounts correctly.

I would like my volumes to mount on boot.  What am I overlooking that is preventing /www/icapture/capture from mounting at boot?

For reference:
From /var/log/dmesg

```
    scsi0 : Virtio SCSI HBA
scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     Google   PersistentDisk   1    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 0:0:2:0: Direct-Access     Google   PersistentDisk   1    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 0:0:3:0: Direct-Access     Google   PersistentDisk   1    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] 1048576000 512-byte logical blocks: (536 GB/500 GiB)
sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] 125829120 512-byte logical blocks: (64.4 GB/60.0 GiB)
sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] 209715200 512-byte logical blocks: (107 GB/100 GiB)
sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sda:
 sdc: sda1
 unknown partition table
sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sdb: unknown partition table
sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I added a section of /var/log/dmesg I read up on the "unkown partition table" message and apparently you can get that if you format the entire disk instead of partitioning.  Looks like Google is recommending *not* partitioning though.  I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: That's for sdb, you appear to be having trouble with sdc?

Comment: You are correct, sdc.  I apologize for introducing confusion :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because errors and omissions in external documentation should be addressed to their author so they can be corrected.

Comment: Do you really think it is a Google problem?  I can certainly go that direction with them, I just find it hard to believe that I set up two and one works fine.  Seems more likely it is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you have followed the documentation correctly then it must be a documentation error.

Comment: I have purchased gold support from Google and will report back the findings.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration of your `/etc/fstab` is correct except `dump` and `pass` values for `/dev/sdc`. Setting `1  1` value for a non-root file system might circumvent auto-mounting under some circumstances. The recommended values for `dump` and `pass` are described in manual of `FSTAB(5)`:

> **The fifth field**, (fs_freq), is used for these filesystems by the
>   dump(8) command to determine which filesys-
>          tems need to be dumped.  If the fifth field is not present, a value of zero is returned and dump will assume
>          that the filesystem does not need to be dumped.
>
> **The sixth field**, (fs_passno), is used by the fsck(8) program to determine  the  order  in  which  filesystem
>          checks  are  done  at reboot time.  **The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and other
>          filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.**  Filesystems within a drive  will  be  checked  sequentially,  but
>          filesystems  on  different  drives  will be checked at the same time to utilize parallelism available in the
>          hardware.  If the sixth field is not present or zero, a value of zero is returned and fsck will assume  that
>          the filesystem does not need to be checked.